# Call different activity method from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a `MainActivity`, `SecondaryActivity` and an `AsyncTask` class.
MainActivity has a method called `doSomething()`

I call the AsyncTask from MainActivity like this:

```
new asyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Which means I can reference the MainActivity in my `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    # activity is defined as this.activity
    activity.doSomething();       
}
```

How can I call the AsyncTask from my SecondaryActivity in a similar manner, because I'd need a reference to my MainActivity to access its methods?

EDIT: I would want the `doSomething()` to be called at all times. So even if it's from SecondActivity, once it finishes its background operation -> doSomething()

The method I'm calling refreshes the screen of MainActivity to show data changes. Secondary activity only calls the AsyncTask when it is being paused/stopped/destroyed but currently the Asynctask finishes after MainActivity has started and so the changes aren't visible.

Comment: Difficult to understand your question. My assumption is you have a MainActivity, SecondaryActivity and a UpsertTask class which extends AsyncTask. Now, you want to use UpsertTask in both activities but call different methods depending on the caller class. Am I correct??

Comment: @Tony That's exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this could be done is by using an event bus. This is a way of passing messages/data between activities. You can post to the bus and then activities can listen for the message if they register.

**EventBus class (seperate)**

```
public class EventBus extends Bus {
    private static final EventBus bus  = new EventBus();   
    public static Bus getInstance() { return bus; }    
    private EventBus() {}
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getInstance().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void asyncDone(String message) {
    foo(message)       
}
```

**AsyncTask class**

```
...
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    EventBus.getInstance().post("My data")
```

Thanks to @theheartbreakpug from Reddit for giving me this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think your AsyncTask in nested in the MainActivity currently. Its better you put it in separate class. Whatever parameter is required by it pass it in its constructor. Let both your activity implement the same interface. Something like this

```
class MainActivity/SecondaryActivity implements DoSomethingListener {
     void doSomething() {
     }
}
```

Also pass your activity reference to AsyncTask in the constructor.

Finally onPostExecute since you have reference to either MainActivity or Secondary Activity. Call activity.doSomething.

Comment: It is a seperate class and not nested

Comment: then you just need to implement a common interface in both the activities and call the interface method onPostExecute()

Comment: This is a fine solution, I like it.

Comment: My `doSomething()` method basically refreshes the screen of `MainActivity` so it can't really be declared in `SecondaryActivity`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to update something in `MainActivity` based on the result of the `AsyncTask` called from `SecondaryActivity`. In that case, I'd suggest calling `SecondaryActivity` with `startActivityForResult`. Then in your `onPostExecute`, call `setResult` to set a flag or some data.

Finally, in `MainActivity` override `onActivityResult` to call `doSomething` when the request code corresponds to `SecondaryActivity`.

Comment: Your answer seems most promising so far. However, I can't `setResult` because the activity is null by the time it is onPostExecute

Comment: I was a bit hasty in calling this the solution, sorry about that. If I do setResult on onPostExecute, the result code doesn't stick/set properly and my mainactivity can't see the code.

Comment: What I suggested is that you do activity.setResult in onPostExecute where activity is instance of SecondaryActivity. Later, when the user goes back to the MainActivity, the doSomething is executed.

Comment: My activity is instance of SecondaryActivity and I setResult in onPostExecute but when onActivityResult is called the result code is 0.

Comment: Then set a flag in `onPostExecute`, call `setResult` just before you call `finish` based on the flag.

Answer (score 1):

So your requirement is to have a single instance of MainActivity. Data in MainActivity may be updated from within MainActivity or from SecondaryActivity. In either case the data to be updated is obtained using an AsyncTask.

**My Suggestion**

Add the following to the MainActivity in manifest, (More about [android:launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) here.)

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

When you are done interacting with SecondaryActivity, do this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATA1", "your_data1");
    intent.putExtra("DATA2", "your_data2");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Then in your MainActivity,

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("DATA1");
    String data2 = intent.getStringExtra("DATA2");
}
```

Then call AsyncTask in MainActivity using data1 and data2.

NOTE: This is one way to approach your problem. There are other approaches such as startActivityForResult() depending on your requirement.

**UPDATE**
If you want to cancel your AsyncTask, call `asyncTask.cancel(true);`
However, this will not ensure your HttpRequest is aborted, as the cancel will take effect after the request has completed. The work-around for this is a bit hackish. After calling cancel(), contineously check if isCancelled() is true, then do `httpRequest.abort()` This will only be the fastest way to finish your async task. Need not necessarily mean the request gets aborted.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. This is a very good solution. Is there anything I can do to avoid potential data loss (if user closes app - so intent never started, or if user navigates to different activity)?

Comment: @Lobstw, see my UPDATE above. Meanwhile, if you find my answer satisfactory, please accept.

Comment: I have solved the problem using an event bus, see solution and please suggest improvements if you have any

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your UpsertTask class.

```
private Context mContext;

public UpsertTask(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);

    if(mContext instanceof MainActivity){
        ((MainActivity) mContext).doSomething();
    }
    else if(mContext instanceof SecondActivity){
        ((SecondActivity) mContext).doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My desired outcome is to have onPostExecute call `doSomething()` at all times. The null I have in the example was just part of a test. So if it's SecondActivity, I would need to get MainActivity at some point

Comment: @Lobstw that sounds like a really really bad design. You should reconsider it.

Comment: @TodorKostov The method I'm calling refreshes the screen of mainactivity to show data changes. Secondary activity only calls the AsyncTask when it is being paused/stopped/destroyed but currently the asynctask finishes after MainActivity has started and so the changes aren't visible.

Comment: Oh! Your question is pretty confusing. So why don't you (1)pass the required data from SecondaryActivity to MainActivity. (2)Finish SecondaryActivity (3) Call AsyncAtask in MainActivity

Comment: @Tony Is there a way of passing data to the MainActivity without creating it again? (So that onCreate isn't called and instead just onRestart?)

Comment: @Lobstw, Sorry for the delayed response. Now that I understand your problem correctly, I have add a new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37916946/1972597

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    # activity is defined as this.activity
    if (activity != null) {
       if(activity instanceof MainActivity) {
         activity.doSomething();
       } else if(activity instanceof SecondaryActivity) {
         activity.doSomethingElse();
       }
    }
}
```

I think that would work. (if you understand your question correctly).